# Team Site template missing on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, team-sites

Since a couple of days, I've seen that if I go to create new subsite on my SharePoint Online tenant , I don't have the option to create a Team Site with the modern experience template.

https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/newsbweb.aspx

[image]

I just see the option to create a Team site with the classic experience.  I've tried in 3 diferent tenants, and is the same on all of them.

Did I miss something? Do I need to activate any feature?

Answer (score 2):

1. Click SharePoint in Apps Panel:

[image]

2. Click "Create Site":
   [image]
3. There will display two Modern Site Template, you can choose one to create:

[image]

The above steps are working for a root modern site collection, but for a modern sub site, I think currently still no possible in the Office 365 UI. The site creation option for modern sites used the root site url under "/sites":
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the SharePoint Admin Preview to create modern Team Sites.

https://tenantName-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/home

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Modern team side using the below option

[image]

The Modern team sites doesn't have any template or site definitions, so you can't create a modern site by using this way https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/newsbweb.aspx ..

Comment: But with the Add page option, I can create a new page, not a subsite.
There is no way to create a modern team subsite via browser?

Comment: Modern page can create as page only not a site, if you want you can create a classic site and top of it you can create modern page and finally you can make that modern page as home page.. that's the only option available

Comment: Thank you Thigavar. That's weird. A couple of days ago I was able to create them. 
If found this post where this options appears https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Modern-subsites/td-p/118856
This is the image
https://gxcuf89792.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/44493iD7F86930D148B60F/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999

Maybe Microsoft hide it again

Comment: its really strange for me , i never seen this option in sub site or site collection creation page.. May be Microsoft is in progress to roll out the new functionality to create modern site as root site..  Ref: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8bfb9788-af9c-41e9-98ef-02ec3e9ceceb/sharepoint-modern-experience-subsites?forum=sharepointgeneral